# Parse TextBox to SqlDbType.Date as "dd.MM.yyyy"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, datetime-parsing, sqldbtype

I want dates to look on page like dd.MM.yyyy.
Me like this way, which is culture-independent.

I don't know how make it right.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eventdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateAddTxtBox.Text;
```

Format Exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I tried many snippets like `DateTime.ParseExact(dateAddTxtBox.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", null)` or using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as well. Nothing helped!

Or maybe it will better done in SQL procedure side, won't it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_history
@user       VARCHAR(20),
@eventdate  DATE,
...
INSERT INTO History(userid, eventdate, ...)
VALUES ((SELECT userid FROM Users.SUsers WHERE suname=@user), @eventdate, ...)
```

All worked pretty good while I haven't format my TextBoxes with pattern:

```
<asp:TextBox id="dateAddTxtBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="AddTxtBoxCalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="dateAddTxtBox" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" ... />
```

UPD:

A little mention >> there was read-only attribute on TextBox.
That's why it didn't work!

Now the question is, is it correct to skip `ReadOnly="True"`? I don't want users to edit dates right in the box.

UPD2:

`ReadOnly="True"` doesn't make a sense at all. It works fine as it should! I don't know why.

Comment: When I tried this DateTime.ParseExact("31.12.1983","dd.MM.yyyy",null), it worked for me. Why don't you put breakpoint and check what your text box is actually returning. Also at the same place try the same that I tried in watch(with some static dates) so that you can know if it is something the problem with your textbox entry or for every date. Just a try

Comment: But it won't with TextBox! Ok, I found the reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify `SqlDbType.Date`. Rely on auto-detection instead, it will work:

```
System.DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(...);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dateValue);
```

Comment: Finally 'ReadOnly' was the reason! If there is no read-only, it works without any conversion or parsing. As is.

Comment: @sublay: Weird. Something is wrong on parsing stage or data-binding stage, not sql execution then.